# Javascript Generate button on a page to autoclick another button every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, automation, click

I want to make an alert that will click another button that's generated without scripts every second. So far I have

```
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Click To Activate";
input.onclick = showAlert;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size: 17px;position: fixed;top: 225px;right:40px:");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

function showAlert()
{
    alert("Active");
}
```

and now i want to click the button, which has the code

```
<span class="b-link js-profile-header-vote" data-choice="yes"></span>
```

every second.

Comment: im a noob and dont know how

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Click To Activate";
input.onclick = showAlert;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size: 17px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

   function showAlert()
    {
      setInterval(function(){ $("#js_profile_header_vote_1").click(); }, 1000);
    }

  $("#js_profile_header_vote_1").click(function(){
    alert("js_profile_header_vote_1 button clicked");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<span class="b-link js-profile-header-vote" id = "js_profile_header_vote_1" data-choice="yes"></span>
  </body>
```